# Understanding the type signature of gfoldl from Data.Data.Data

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature, scrap-your-boilerplate

[`Data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data) defines as one of its core functions [`gfoldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Data.html#v:gfoldl):

```
gfoldl
  :: (Data a)
  => (forall d b. Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b) 
  -> (forall g. g -> c g)   
  -> a  
  -> c a
```

What's the purpose of `c` and `c (d -> b)` in it? Why isn't it just a regular fold, something like

```
gfoldl'
  :: (Data a)
  => (forall d. Data d => r -> d -> r)
  -> r
  -> a  
  -> r
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea is that a value of an algebraic datatype in Haskell has the form

```
C x_1 x_2 ... x_n
```

where `C` is a constructor and the `x_i` are the arguments. What

```
gfoldl app con
```

does is to turn such a value into

```
con C `app` x_1 `app` x_2 ... `app` x_n
```

thereby turning an `a` into a `c a`. Let's assume the type of `C` is

```
C :: T_1 -> T_2 -> ... -> T_n -> D
```

then let's look at the types of the intermediate expressions:

```
con C                                   :: c (T_1 -> T_2 -> ... -> T_n -> D)
con C `app` x_1                         :: c (T_2 -> ... -> T_n -> D)
con C `app` x_1 `app` x_2               :: c (... -> T_n -> D)
con C `app` x_1 `app` x_2 ... `app` x_n :: c D
```

The parameterization over `c` allows all these intermediate types to be
different. If we'd use a simple fold such as `gfoldl'` instead, then all
these intermediate types would have to be the same.

The motivation for `gfoldl` is to be a
single generalization that lets you express the SYB functions `gmapQ` and `gmapT` (and a few others). The types of `gmapQ` and `gmapT` are:

```
gmapQ :: Data a => (forall d. Data d => d -> u) -> a -> [u]
gmapT :: Data a => (forall b. Data b => b -> b) -> a -> a
```

While `gmapQ` collapses an `a` into a uniform list of `u`s and could
be expressed using `gfoldl'`, this wouldn't be possible for `gmapT`.

However, with `gfoldl`, we can use `c = Identity` to enable us to get
something like `gmapT`, and `c = Const` to get something like `gmapQ`.

For more details, you may also want to look at the paper [Scrap your boilerplate Reloaded](http://www.andres-loeh.de/SYB0.html) which shows that `gfoldl` is an ordinary (yet
higher-order) fold of a datatype that is called `Spine` in that paper.

The use of the identity and constant functors to obtain both transforming and
updating behaviour from a single underlying representation has some
similarity to how you obtain the lens operations from "van Laarhoven" lenses.

Comment: “parameterization over `c` allows all these intermediate types to be different” – could you elaborate? That doesn't really make obvious sense.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In `gfoldl'` all `c X` occurrences are `r`, i.e., they all have to be the same type. With `c X`, I can still have all of them be the same type, such as in `Const r X` which is isomorphic to `r`. But I can also have them all be different, such as e.g. in `Identity X` which is isomorphic to `X`.